# Dedicated video memory 0mb, system video memory 0mb. Is my Intel and Nvidia graphic cards are not working?

Tags: memory, graphics-card, intel-graphics, nvidia-graphics-card

System configuration : HP model - 15-r014tx, i5, 4gb ram, 2gb NVidia, intel graphic adapter, windows 8.1.

When I right click desktop > screen resolution > advance setting. It shows following information:

```
Intel(R) HD graphic adapter Information:
Total Available graphic memory - 1792 mb 
Dedicated video memory - 0 mb 
system video memory - 0 mb
shared system memory - 1792 mb
```

But when I give command "dxdiag" in run, it shows following:

```
Card name: Intel(R) HD Graphics Family
Display Memory: 4008 MB
Dedicated Memory: 1994 MB
Shared Memory: 2013 MB
```

So my questions is that is my Intel graphic cards not working properly? And also want to check is my NVidia graphic card is working good?

Answer (score 0):

The obvious thing is that since you can actual use the system, see something on screen indicates that at least one of your video cards is working.

Here's the thing though, a cursory search does not indicate whether this particular device is a dual graphics card capable laptop (some do this to save power but provide a extra graphical processing power if required for gaming. It can be done manually or automatically via hardware and/or software).

If it is see if you can disable one or the other and see whether the system still runs (check BIOS for options).

I wouldn't trust only two programs to see whether everything is working okay. Here's the other problem they may work very differently. A standard graphics driver versus Direct X access may be very different. The birth/inception of Direct X was to achieve higher performance (through lower level access) for gaming purposes which may explain the memory disparity.

I'd be looking at other video diagnostic programs available online to see whether everything was working perfectly to be honest. These two programs are simply not enough.

http://www.3dmark.com/
http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-free-benchmark-programs/